# Searching CSV file using user input with wild card

Tags: python, json, csv

I am working with an api. My call generates a json file and a csv file. I am able to generate Company ID's and they name of said company. The company names we have are specific to location / building etc. I want the user to be able to search the csv file with a wild card and return that value for instance:

```
1.) Company ID: 123456     Company Name: TerrorLand Building 1
2.) Company ID: 123457     Company Name: Terrorland Building 6

Which Company would you like?
2
Company ID: 123457 Company Name: Terrorland Building 6
```

I want the user to be able to search terror. Then continue to drill down until they reach the company name / id they specifically need.

How can i search CSV elements using user inputs / wildcards?

```
    import requests
    import json
    import csv

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Basic API 
    KEY'}

    #below is the api request

    response = requests.get('URL', headers=headers).json()

    #this is where the response is dumped

    with open('response.json','w') as json_file:
           json.dump(response, json_file, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)

    with open('response.json', 'r') as x:
            x  = json.load(x)

            f = csv.writer(open('test.csv', "w"))
            f.writerow(["Id", "Name"])
                for x in x:
             f.writerow([x["Id"],
                        x["Name"]])

                 search_for = ['ID','Name']

                 with open('test.csv') as inf, open('out.csv','w') as outf:
                     reader = csv.reader(inf)
                     writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', 
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                     for row in reader:
                          if row[0] in search_for:
                               print('Found: {}'.format(row))
                                    writer.writerow(row)
```

'''

Comment: Does `if search_for in row[0]` work?

Comment: You could use the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module as a simple way to get Unix shell-style wildcard support.